# why its taking so much of time creating react app on windows using command npx

Tags: reactjs, npx

I used command

```
 'npx create-react-app sample-app --use-npm'
```

on screen it shows like thus

> ```
> `Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
> Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...`
> ```

and it halts for infinite time.

can someone from react team help us on this. I am sure many people are facing this kind of issue.

Comment: 5 MBPS is just way too slow man. I got a 80 MBPS direct to home line (not one of those shared apartment connections) and it still takes 2 to 4 minutes. you will just have to wait it out. also, instead of creating a new app, once an app is created, just keep a copy of it for new project creation. that would save some time.

Answer (score 0):

Creating React App takes a span of minutes, definitely. From the official documentation, it's enough to just use `npx create-react-app my-app` to create the app.

Taking much time is dependent on the network. May be you should check your internet speed

Comment: Yes, my network speed is 5 MBPS download. I think that much is sufficient. still I would say creating react app is way more hectic than angular. angular app creating using cli is much easier.

Comment: If you just need the app to practice, you can generate the CRA and be duplicating it whenever you need it instead of doing a new CRA.

Comment: how can I skip CRA is it necessary? I don't think without that I learning react is difficult.